# Spring mailSender throwing nullPointerException

Tags: spring, nullpointerexception

I want to send a plain text email using spring framework. I am working using netbeans IDE and I have added mail.jar, common.jar in my dependencies folder as well. My code is as follows:

```
 @Service("emailService")
    public class EmailService {

        @Inject
        private MailSender mailSender;



         @RequestMapping(method = RequestMethod.POST)
        public void sendMail(String from, String to, String subject, String body) {
             System.out.println("=============from:"+from);
                 System.out.println("==========to:"+to);
                 System.out.println("subject: "+subject);
                 System.out.println("body: "+body);

            SimpleMailMessage message = new SimpleMailMessage();

            message.setFrom(from);
            message.setTo(to);
            message.setSubject(subject);
            message.setText(body);
            this.mailSender.send(message); 
                System.out.println("----------after sendig mail");

        }
}
```

I am getting NullPointerException for this.mailSender.send(message);

my applicationContext.xml is as follows:

```
 <!-- Required for sending mail using spring framework -->
<context:component-scan base-package="net.codejava.spring" />

<bean id="mailSender" class="org.springframework.mail.javamail.JavaMailSenderImpl">
    <property name="host" value="smtp.gmail.com" />
    <property name="port" value="587" />
    <property name="username" value="USERNAME" />
    <property name="password" value="PASSWRD" />
    <property name="javaMailProperties">
        <props>
            <prop key="mail.transport.protocol">smtp</prop>
            <prop key="mail.smtp.auth">true</prop>
            <prop key="mail.smtp.starttls.enable">true</prop>
        </props>
    </property>
</bean>
```

Please tell me how to get over it.

Comment: can you share the stacktrace

Comment: somehow your mailsender which you created in `xml` file is not being autowired and try adding setter method.

Comment: Thanks for the response. I have been able to resolve it.  I added the follwoing lines in my code

Comment: Try message.saveChanges(); before the send message.

Comment: And also try message.setRecipients(Message.RecipientType.TO, to);

Comment: possible duplicate of [Why is my Spring @Autowired field null?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19896870/why-is-my-spring-autowired-field-null)

Answer (score 0):

Just Change `@Inject` to `@Autowired`